# How to get currently selected keyboard?

Tags: android

I am developing a custom keyboard, and I need to get the currently selected keyboard name. 
I tried using this:

```
  String keyboard = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

But, it doesnt work. Whenever user presses select button, I give them the options to choose the keyboards and when the user selects one, I want to get the name of the keyboard or its ID would work too. 
This is what I have used to let the user choose the keyboard. 
I just need to get the currently selected keyboard ID

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Any help regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> keyboardInfo = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
```

Comment: Might be useful, but I need the no sooner than the user selects from the showInputMethodPicker method